# How can I use a custom view of generic type (CustomView<T>) in android layout xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, lint

I am trying to use a CustomView<T> in layout xml. But getting **"missing type arguments for generic class CustomView."**

To ignore this issue I created a sub class of CustomView<T> which resolved the issue. But my goal was not achieved completely because this view will be used in multiple places with different type arguments so I am looking for some general solution.

I tried to resolve it by lint.xml by adding the below line but it is not resolved.

```
<issue id="rawtypes" severity="ignore"/>
```

Please suggest some trick to resolve it.